# Release memories - android

Tags: android, memory-leaks, bitmap, release

I read some essays about releasing memories for Bitmap objects. I create a sample to test this problem as below.

MainActivity class:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private Bitmap bitmap;
    private InputStream inputStream;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        try {
            inputStream = getAssets().open("image1.jpg");
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
        }catch(Exception e){
            Log.v("hoabao91", e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        try {
            inputStream.close();
            inputStream = null;
            bitmap.recycle();
            bitmap = null;
        }catch(Exception e){
            Log.v("hoabao91", e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public void click(View view){
        startActivity(new Intent(this, TestActivity.class));
    }
}
```

TestActivity class:

```
public class TestActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_test);
    }
}
```

activity_main view:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Submit"
        android:onClick="click"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

activity_test:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.hoa.test2.TestActivity">

</RelativeLayout>
```

I use android debug tool to track **allocated memory**

This is a status when I deploy the app

[image]

The system allocate to all objects including bitmap object 11.96 MB

Then I click the button "Submit" to go to TestActivity, the method onPause() will be called and the bitmap object will be release by recycle(). **But status of allocated memory doesn't decrease**. In contrast, it increase a little more (11.99 MB)!

Someone help me with explaining about that or giving me a solution to decrease allocated memory. To avoid leak of memory for large app.